# Google Chrome browser update conflicts

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser

I am using Google Chrome on Mac

- iMac(21.5-inch, Mid 2011)
- macOS: 10.11.6 (15G31)

After updating to 50 I am facing a strange problem.

Chrome menu says that my browser is out of date(Which is right) 

But about page say that it is up to date(Which is wrong).

Current Google Chrome version is 50.0.2661.94 latest is  52.0.2743.116?

You can see this in screenshot:
[image]

I try but can't find any way to update manually. I try to search for the solution there are many users with update issue but not similar to this.

Thanks to giving time for this question. Let me know if anyone have any clue. Thanks again.

Comment: Mine says 'Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)' - up-to-date too - what typically helps is to close and kill all chrome processes (anything that starts with Chrome * and Google*); sometimes the update processes gets a hickup with two concurrent tries.

Comment: Thanks @Aganju for time and suggestion. I have tried that and also restart mac.

Comment: You may just try uninstalling and reinstalling if nothing else works.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC I have done that. it solves problem temporary. But when new version release I face the same problem.